# What does "friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list)" mean?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, friend

So I was given an assignment with starter code to implement a linked list (which I have done with an unsorted doubly linked list successfully) and in the starter code in the given header file there was a friend declaration that seems to have the goal of allowing me to print the linked list using the `cout` statement. This is the header file; note that I wrote everything in the private section.

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_
#define _LINKED_LIST_

#include <ostream>

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void add(char ch);
    bool find(char ch);
    bool del(char ch);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list);

private:
    struct node
    {
        char data;
        node * next;
        node * prev;
    };
    node * head, * tail;
};

#endif // _LINKED_LIST_
```

In `main`, which was also part of the starter code, the teacher wrote `cout << list;` which leads me to believe the goal of the friend statement in the header file was to allow list to be printed to the console easily. Normally I wouldn't care but if I don't comment out the `cout << list;` statements then the linker gives me the following error for every instance of `cout << list;`

```
app.o: In function 'main':
[code directory]/app.cpp:[line the statement is on]: undefined reference to
'operator<<(std::ostream&, LinkedList&)'
```

**My question is**, what does `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list)` mean and why does `cout << list;` cause this error? The code executes fine without the statements and since I'm using the instructor's makefile to assemble the assignment, I figure that isn't the issue.

app.cpp is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

void find(LinkedList& list, char ch)
{
    if (list.find(ch))
        cout << "found ";
    else
        cout << "did not find ";
    cout << ch << endl;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList  list;

    list.add('x');
    list.add('y');
    list.add('z');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    list.del('y');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    list.del('x');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    list.del('z');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It means you declared, friended, and most importantly, are *using* `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list);`, but never actually *defined* it in a translation unit that is linked with your code. Declaring it was the first step; you still need to *implement* it. Unrelated, the second parameter should ideally be a const-reference, not just a reference, as output operators rarely modify the object being written.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what does `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list)` mean

The [friend declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declares a non-member function, and makes it friend of the class, meaning it can access the `private` and `protected` members of the class `LinkedList`.

> and why does `cout << list;` cause this error?

Since it's just a declaration, you need to define it by yourself. That's why you get an undefined reference linker error.

You might define it inside the class (and defined inline)

```
class LinkedList
{
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list) {
        // output something
        return out;
    }
    ...
};
```

Or define it outside of the class:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list) {
    // output something
    return out;
}
```

BTW: I suggest you to make the 2nd parameter type `const LinkedList&`; it should not be modified inside the `operator<<`.

Comment: I defined the second function you wrote inside of the cpp implementation file, but I'm still getting an out of scope error for node, current, and head.

Comment: @LegionDaeth Compile error? Please show the error message. How are using `head`? Is it `list.head`?

Comment: I tried using list.head and list.node but I get a "invalid use of ‘struct LinkedList::node’" error and a "current was not declared error" in reference to "list.node *current;". I've added the code to the question to clarify what I've written.

Comment: @LegionDaeth `list.node` should be `LinkedList::node`;

Answer (score 4):

The goal of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list)` actually *is* to be able to do e. g. `std::cout << someList;`

Part of your task now is to write such an operator (and as you haven't done so so far, you get the linker error...); it will be written outside of your class, such as this:

```cpp
class LinkedList
{
    /* ... */
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list)
{
    /* output the list however it is appropriate */
}
```

This is all fine so far - only one single problem: As the operator is defined outside the class, it can only access the public interface of the LinkedList class.

And here comes the friend declaration into play: With this declaration, you  explicitely allow the `operator<<` to access the private members, too; in your case especially the `node` struct and the head and tail members which otherwise all would have been inaccessible for the operator.

Comment: I copied that function verbatim but I'm still getting an out of scope error for node, head, and current which are a part of my outputting algorithm.

Comment: @LegionDaeth Did you follow songyuanyao's proposition to add `const`-ness to the list parameter? Then you have to add it at both friend declaration *and* implementation, otherwise these get different operators.

Answer (score 0):

You have guessed correctly that the goal of that function is to print an instance of the class to the provided output stream. When used in this context (two arguments, a reference to an output stream and a reference to an object of some kind, and returning the stream), the `<<` operator is typically called the stream insertion operator.

The header declares the friend function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, LinkedList&)`, and it is referenced in the `main` function written by the instructor. If you want full credit for the assignment, you need to implement that function. The`friend` qualifier means that this is a free function rather than a member function but that it can access a `LinkedList` objects protected and private members.